# Is there a shortcut key to bring up the Launch Pad on an older apple keyboard?

Tags: macos

It's a white iMac, I think perhaps 2007 model. Here is the keyboard currently:

[image]

There is one that works for Mission Control, but not for Launch Pad.

Do you think there is a way to configure one to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simply configure a shortcut of your liking for it in:

*System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Launchpad & Dock*

[image]

Comment: I like this even better :)

Comment: @gentmatt: haha perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

Check in *System Preferences > Mission Control* what key is assigned for Launchpad. You can customize the settings of course.

Note that per default pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> for example will work as a media key (change volume in your case). So you need to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> instead.